# filter by nested object of an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of object

```
[  
   {  
      "uuid":"470ab23b-dab4-44ee-920f-36ea277a7c21",
      "distributeStoreUuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
      "substoreUuid":"9540c742-ba85-4086-bbc6-da0da9fbe31f",
      "substore__store_uuid":"e84ebdca-b676-4abd-9943-9a97abe8fcfe",
      "substore__ctrl_location_uuid":"619a55f1-789c-49a1-8870-14e3f66bdc1d",
      "substore__lt_status_uuid":"6d11644a-dd85-4201-a20a-4c5d186af601",
      "storedistribution":{  
         "uuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
         "acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid":"80fb9423-f979-4f53-841c-9f6af5f16ed3",
         "acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid":"acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
         "acceptanceTask__lt_status_uuid":"15ceae6c-a8cb-416c-a6f3-ed7366740841",
      },
   }
]
```

with the following workaround

```
data.find(item => item.acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid === uuid)
```

but it doesn't work if simply use `find`. I also have try `filter` and confusedly with `reduce`. What is the right way to get array of object filter by its nested key object

Comment: the question and requirement is not clear

Comment: Do you want just to find an element or filter the whole array?

Comment: If you use find, it will obviously return the first matching element. You need filter to filter through the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to get the elements with the same `v.uuid` and  `v.storedistribution.acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid`

```js
var arr = [  
    {  
    "uuid":"470ab23b-dab4-44ee-920f-36ea277a7c21",
    "distributeStoreUuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
    "substoreUuid":"9540c742-ba85-4086-bbc6-da0da9fbe31f",
    "substore__store_uuid":"e84ebdca-b676-4abd-9943-9a97abe8fcfe",
    "substore__ctrl_location_uuid":"619a55f1-789c-49a1-8870-14e3f66bdc1d",
    "substore__lt_status_uuid":"6d11644a-dd85-4201-a20a-4c5d186af601",
    "storedistribution":{  
    "uuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
    "acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid":"80fb9423-f979-4f53-841c-9f6af5f16ed3",
    "acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid":"acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
    "acceptanceTask__lt_status_uuid":"15ceae6c-a8cb-416c-a6f3-ed7366740841",
    },
    },
    {  
    "uuid":"470ab23b-dab4-44ee-920f-36ea277a7c21",
    "distributeStoreUuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
    "substoreUuid":"9540c742-ba85-4086-bbc6-da0da9fbe31f",
    "substore__store_uuid":"e84ebdca-b676-4abd-9943-9a97abe8fcfe",
    "substore__ctrl_location_uuid":"619a55f1-789c-49a1-8870-14e3f66bdc1d",
    "substore__lt_status_uuid":"6d11644a-dd85-4201-a20a-4c5d186af601",
    "storedistribution":{  
    "uuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
    "acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid":"80fb9423-f979-4f53-841c-9f6af5f16ed3",
    "acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid":"acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
    "acceptanceTask__lt_status_uuid":"15ceae6c-a8cb-416c-a6f3-ed7366740841",
    },
    },
    {  
    "uuid":"470ab23b-dab4-44ee-920f-fffffffffff",
    "distributeStoreUuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
    "substoreUuid":"9540c742-ba85-4086-bbc6-da0da9fbe31f",
    "substore__store_uuid":"e84ebdca-b676-4abd-9943-9a97abe8fcfe",
    "substore__ctrl_location_uuid":"619a55f1-789c-49a1-8870-14e3f66bdc1d",
    "substore__lt_status_uuid":"6d11644a-dd85-4201-a20a-4c5d186af601",
    "storedistribution":{  
    "uuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
    "acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid":"80fb9423-f979-4f53-841c-9f6af5f16ed3",
    "acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid":"470ab23b-dab4-44ee-920f-fffffffffff",
    "acceptanceTask__lt_status_uuid":"15ceae6c-a8cb-416c-a6f3-ed7366740841",
    },
    },
 ];

 var result = arr.filter(v=>v.uuid === v.storedistribution.acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid);

 console.log( result );
```

Comment: is not the same answer given below?

Comment: where do you get `v.uuid`?

Comment: @MuhaiminCS each element is `v` so to acccess the `uuid` you have to `v.uuid`

Comment: @Sajeetharan Are you asking if my answer is the same as yours?

Comment: @Sajeetharan For the record, your answer is different. Yours is searching the array with `t.storedistribution.acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid == 'acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022'` .. Static. Mine is not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [  
   {  
      "uuid":"470ab23b-dab4-44ee-920f-36ea277a7c21",
      "distributeStoreUuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
      "substoreUuid":"9540c742-ba85-4086-bbc6-da0da9fbe31f",
      "substore__store_uuid":"e84ebdca-b676-4abd-9943-9a97abe8fcfe",
      "substore__ctrl_location_uuid":"619a55f1-789c-49a1-8870-14e3f66bdc1d",
      "substore__lt_status_uuid":"6d11644a-dd85-4201-a20a-4c5d186af601",
      "storedistribution":{  
         "uuid":"af0309b5-5b84-46e5-b59f-5a35e84ffd92",
         "acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid":"80fb9423-f979-4f53-841c-9f6af5f16ed3",
         "acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid":"acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
         "acceptanceTask__lt_status_uuid":"15ceae6c-a8cb-416c-a6f3-ed7366740841",
      }
   }
];

var result = array.filter(t=>t.storedistribution.acceptanceTaskDetails__acceptanceTaskUuid == 'acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022');
console.log(result);
```